# Почему возникает ошибка при импорте и создание экземпляра класса в reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет, у меня в первом файле есть вот такой класс

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch";
export default class Ajax extends fetch{

    get(url){
        return fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                    return response.json();
                }
            ).catch(function(err) {
                alert('Error GET')
            });
    }

}
```

Я его испортирую в другой файл и пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса

```
import {Ajax} from 'ajax'
ajaxinstance = new Ajax();
ajaxinstance.get('http://example.com/');
```

Но при создании мне говорит

**TypeError: _ajax.Ajax is not a constructor**

Почему так происходит? во всех примерах которые я нагугли все так написано....

Comment: Импортирвоание по умолчанию нужно юзать без `{}`.

Comment: Да спасибо помогло